# CSS: inline all elements that fit on first line, line break after each next element

Tags: css, less

**no javascript and no screen width media queries**

I am trying to find a *css-only* way to achieve the situation depicted in below image. I couldn't find a way to create the following:

- a line of blocks (inline blocks or floated blocks) with variable width, aligned to the right of the line using float:right or right text align
- elements that don't fit on the line, wrap to the next line. All elements after the first line have their own line.

I've been experimenting around with several strategies to no avail, I have a feeling that flexbox might help but I'm not very experienced with flexbox and couldn't find a way to use it.

[image]

---

A few things that I have tried:

1. try to put the elements' content in a :before pseudo element, using content:attr(data-content). The element itself would have no width. On the next line there would be a left floating element with a width of 99.9% that pushes each element on a next line. The problem with this is that the elements on the first line should maintain their normal width and I didn't find a way to do that. The :first-line pseudo-selector is limited to words on the line and doesn't work for inline containers on the line
2. Alternative to above method: also add :after pseudo elements which are absolutely positioned and have the same content as the :befores. The :before elements would only show on the first line and don't wrap, the :after elements would form the vertical list on the right. Also with this way I walked into a dead end.

---

**UPDATE:** 
I made a (less) fiddle that works when the elements' widths are fixed and equal. Unfortunately fixed width, so not yet what I want to achieve. If you want to help me you could perhaps use this as a starting point. I put the content in a :before so perhaps it could overflow the element and somehow fix the element width to auto.

currently CHROME only: http://jsfiddle.net/2px3b63j/7/

html:

```
<div class="pusher"></div>
<nav>
  <a data-title="First" href="#"></a><a data-title="Second" href="#"></a><a data-title="Third" href="#"></a><a data-title="Fourth" href="#"></a><a data-title="Fifth" href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

less:

```
@h: 3em;
@w:6em;
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 0.9rem sans-serif;
  background: #666;
}

.pusher {
  float: left;
  width: ~"calc(100% - " (@w * 1.01) ~")";
  height: @h * 6;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 @h, 100% @h, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  background: white;
  height: @h;
  line-height:0;
  a {
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    width: @w;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: @h;
    line-height: @h;
    &:before {
      content: attr(data-title);
    }
  }
}
```

LINK TO ANSWER: https://jsfiddle.net/ky83870x/1/ doesn't work in Internet Explorer but I assume it works in Edge. If anyone can find a way to make it work in IE, I will be very interested to know

Comment: No, flexbox can't do that. It can do the wrapping but it cant put each "*next item on it's own line*"

Comment: Aziz, as I said, and showed in the image, they have a variable width

Comment: I think this is best that you can do with flexbox or just css https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/86/

Comment: Aziz, the containers contain a word of which the length can vary, so the css cannot make any assumptions about the width of the elements

Comment: Nenad, as I can understand you believe that my problem cannot be solved. I will edit the question with attempts I have made

Comment: Are you accepting solutions in LESS? If so you may want to tag your question [less].

Comment: @BoltClock how would this be solved with LESS?

Comment: less is css so of course i accept it

Comment: @Aziz: I don't know, but the OP provided LESS code to start with so I figured they might be content with a LESS workaround.

Comment: @BoltClock the point of our response was that less is not more powerful than css. You don't have more possibilities in less than you have in css because less just compiles to css. It is just a useful way to make your stylesheets shorter, more logical, etc. If a problem cannot be solved in css, it cannot be solved in less, so there is no such thing as a "less workaround". The problem is solved by the way, see the accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One posibility to get your output using flex box.

Make the flexbox so narrow that any child will fit. That forces the children to go one in a row.

Add a pseudo element before the first child to force an extra margin.

Justify the flex as needed

And place the flex to the right, because now everything is to the left.

The elements are color coded to see easily what is happening

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 10px;
  left: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container div {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  margin-left: -500px;
  flex-basis: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>Ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>Consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
  <div>Unde saepe</div>
  <div>Placeat neque mollitia</div>
  <div>Accusamus fuga</div>
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>Ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div>Consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
  <div>Unde saepe</div>
  <div>Placeat neque mollitia</div>
  <div>Accusamus fuga</div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW that actually works! This is the kind of css hack that I was searching for. Thank you so much. Here is an edited fiddle that uses the entire screen width instead of 500px: https://jsfiddle.net/ky83870x/1/. Doesnt work in IE11- btw, I guess because of the many IE flexbox issues. Thanks again

Comment: So the  "width" of the parent is determined by setting left offset with negative margin to :before? It's a nice solution but not sure if flexible enough.

Comment: only issue so far is browser support, IE up until at least version 11 doesn't have a correct implementation of flexbox

Comment: Happy that it helped ! I have been trying to get it working in IE, but no luck ...